# pressure tank in unheated cabin

Tags: well

Can I set up the pressure tank set up in an unheated cabin ? I'm ok draining it when not in use for a month or two, but I don't have an air compressor - the drain would be whats on the tank tee and that's it.

Referencing:

[Can I operate a well pump with no pressure tank by using the breaker as a switch?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/157662/can-i-operate-a-well-pump-with-no-pressure-tank-by-using-the-breaker-as-a-switch)

Thanks.

Comment: What is the temps in this area it would have to get in the low 20's possibly lower to freeze that large volume of  water if the day time temps are 40 or so.

Comment: Daytime temps here not in 40's for another month or so.  1.5 Months to be safe.

Comment: If you have additional information that you believe would enhance your question or clarify details then add it to the question instead of posting in the answer section.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a special type of modulating pump  you will need a pressure tank. In most cases the pressure tank is used to stop the pump from short cycling. If you forgo a pressure tank the pump turn on and off continuously greatly reducing the life expectancy of the pump. Draining it would be recommended if you're not using it and away. If the place is cold you can also use RV Plumbing antifreeze to ensure no residual water freezes. Flush it out when ready to use.

Side note, 
After reading your other post. 
Yes you can operate the pump from the breaker with just a pipe connected to nothing. Be careful to not dead head the pump, meaning don't run it with a valve closed. Without a pressure switch to turn it off at high pressure you can hurt the pump or burst a pipe (unlikely but possible)

Comment: The use case is temporary - I just need water coming out of a pipe until risk of freezing is done.  The pipe it self is going to be protected with heat tape.  This question though is regarding the pressure tank - its in a closet, any way to just heat that area for now ?

Comment: Just don't use the tank at all for now. If you must, put a small thermostatic electric heater in the closet and close the door. You only need to use the tank if the pressure switch is wired in with the pump.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can turn the breaker on and fill a drum or pail, whatever you need then turn the breaker off. This would be Similar to flushing the toilet and washing your hands, the pump kicks in fills and shuts off not a short cycle issue at all.